# How to scale a two dimensional array in javascript fast?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix

Given 2 dimensional array a:

```
let a = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0], 
    [0, 1, 1, 1], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0], 
    [0, 0, 1, 1] 
]
```

How can I scale it by a given factor? For example, array b is array a scaled by 4:

```
let b =[ 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

This is the code I wrote to perform this operation but it is slow (client browser: Chrome) when dealing with large arrays (200 x 200) and scaling lets say by a facor of 16.

```
// scale an array by a factor of 'scale'

const scaledMatrixArray = (arr, scale) => {
        let newArr = [];
        arr.forEach((el) => {
            let newArrRow = [];
            el.forEach((el) => {
                for (let j = 0; j < scale; j++) {
                    newArrRow.push(el);
                }
            });
            for(let i = 0; i < scale ; i++) {
                newArr.push(newArrRow);
            }
        });
        return newArr;
    };
```

I understand my implementation is some variant of O(n^2) and is highly inefficient. I am looking for a better way to do this or a library that does it better and faster. My end result is that my *N X N* array with over N > 200 can scale to an array of 800 x 800 in the most efficient, fastest and least memory intensive way.

Comment: Note that any implementation that takes an `N*N` array and scales it by some factor `M` is going to produce a total of `N*N*M` values and is therefore going to be O(mn^2)

Comment: @Hamms so there's no way to make this faster?

Comment: Oh, actually it's going to be a total of `N*N*M*M` values and therefore O(n^2m^2)

Comment: There might be some ways to make it marginally faster, but if your end goal is to get an array of size `N*M` by `N*M`, then you're gonna have to do something `N*M*N*M` times

Comment: depending on what exactly you're trying to do, there are probably faster/better ways to do it than making a gigantic array

Comment: If you're really concerned about speed, you can use `for` loops everywhere rather than `forEach`, it has a tiny performance increase when doing huge numbers of repetitive operations.

Comment: @Hamm, The reason I need the array is to use the easystar.js library for path finding. The array stores location information (walkable tiles) for an image 800x800 pixels. The scaling is because the original location information was 50x50 pixels. I'll try to approach the solution from a different angle I think, as you suggest.

Comment: seems like you can just find the path on the 50x50 matrix and multiply the resulting path points by 16. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Slai, that makes too much sense. Let me go and try that now. I'm having a slow brain day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a very reduced way, using `Array().fill`, It's running faster than the other answers at least in my browser.

I added two versions, one using spread operator, and the other ussing `.apply`. I'm getting faster results with `apply`.

```js
function scaleSpread(array, factor) {
 const scaled = [];

 for(const row of array) {
  let x = [];

  for(const item of row)
   x.push(...Array(factor).fill(item));

  scaled.push(...Array(factor).fill(x));
 }

 return scaled;
}

function scaleApply(array, factor) {
 const scaled = [];

 for(const row of array) {
  let x = [];

  for(const item of row)
   x.push.apply(x, Array(factor).fill(item));

  scaled.push.apply(scaled, Array(factor).fill(x));
 }

 return scaled;
}

function scaleConcat(array, factor) {
 let scaled = [];

 for(const row of array) {
  let x = [];

  for(const item of row)
   x = x.concat(Array(factor).fill(item));

  scaled = scaled.concat(Array(factor).fill(x));
 }

 return scaled;
}

var a = [ [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 0, 1, 1] ]

console.time('spread');
scaleSpread(a, 10000);
console.timeEnd('spread');

console.time('apply');
scaleApply(a, 10000);
console.timeEnd('apply');

console.time('concat');
scaleConcat(a, 10000);
console.timeEnd('concat');
```

**EDIT:** Added a version using `.concat` since apply and spread causes `Maximum call stack size exceeded` with very large arrays.

Comment: @EmmanuelNK added another version, using `apply` which is even faster, at least in my browser.

Comment: Yep this is defnly faster in my browser too.

Comment: I didn't posted yesterday, because in node it was slower than Emmanuel's. What number's are you getting? `spread: 7.900ms
apply: 1.200ms`

Comment: I doubt that `apply` is faster than direct call to `push`. Anyhoos, spread is ~10ms and apply ~7.6ms for me

Comment: I doubt it too. But I'm pushing items * factor at once, instead of loop & push.

Comment: Spread it there.. it treats your `Array(factor).fill(x)` as an `arguments` which is an array, and `push` accepts multiple elements as arguments. Not sure which is faster, `x.push.apply(x, Array(factor).fill(item));` or `x.push(...Array(factor).fill(item));`

Comment: Added a `.concat` version too, to avoid ` Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: okay wow this is definitely much faster. I get 2.8ms in my browser for concat

Comment: You cannot just benchmark them this way, the first function call will always take the largest time no matter how fast it was, the second two will benefit from caching and will appear as if the are faster. You must try every function separately.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is using a `for loop`, to iterate an n-dimensional array for the decided `n` times.

This uses [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method, by grabbing the source value and inserting it to the array at certain index.

PS: The source array (which is `a`), is mutated here. But, you can always clone the original array and create `b` for the result as you wanted.

```js
var a = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0], 
    [0, 0, 1, 1] 
  ],
  scale = 4,
  scaleTheArray = function (arrayToScale, nTimes) {
    for (var idx = 0, i = 0, len = arrayToScale.length * nTimes; i < len; i++) {
      var elem = arrayToScale[idx];

      /* Insert the element into (idx + 1) */
      arrayToScale.splice(idx + 1, 0, elem);

      /* Add idx for the next elements */
      if ((i + 1) % nTimes === 0) {
        idx += nTimes + 1;
      }
    }
  };

console.time('testScale');

/* 1. Expand each of the a[n] length */
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
  var arr = a[i];

  scaleTheArray(arr, scale - 1);
}

/* 2. Expand each of the a length */
scaleTheArray(a, scale - 1);

console.timeEnd('testScale');
```

Comment: Mother of god this is fast. `10000 scale = 1328.18995ms`

Comment: @Sphinx Well, the challenge in this approach is to not roll over. That's why I declared `idx`, `i` and `len` on the `for` initial expression.

Comment: @Zze Too bad for you, for me `10000 scale = 302.428955078125ms` 8)

Comment: @choz Stayed tuned for my personal pc report later today!

Comment: This is incredibly fast... I'm getting `10000 scale = 367.779052734375ms`

Comment: @EmmanuelNK Where are you testing it? In node? Because in my computer, node 8.9.4 this is 10 times slower than your solution.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande what scale are you using? I'm testing this in Chrome

Comment: 10000 scale, I thought it was for node actually :), all my tests were futile :P

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I probably should have mentioned that. sorry. The code I'm writing is to be used in the client browser. That's where the arrays are to be created

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Node v9.8.0, It's testScale: 312.806ms for 10k scale for me.  I don't see which ends might make these differ since node and chrome use the same engine to run javascript.

Comment: @EmmanuelNK gonna post an answer then, my method is faster than choz' at least in my browser. Choz and EmmanuelNK care to tell me what you're getting after I post it?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I've tested yours. It s indeed way faster. I get 2.8ms (concat) on your method and ~300ms on Choz' method

Answer (score 3):

In general, less function calls = less overhead :

```js
function scale1D(arr, n) 
{
  for (var i = arr.length *= n; i; ) 
    arr[--i] = arr[i / n | 0]
}

function scale2D(arr, n) 
{
  for (var i = arr.length; i; )
    scale1D(arr[--i], n)

  scale1D(arr, n)
}

var a = [ [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 0, 1, 1] ]
console.time( 1e5 )
scale2D(a, 1e5)
console.timeEnd( 1e5 )

var b = [ [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 0, 1, 1] ]
scale2D(b, 4)
console.log( JSON.stringify( b ).replace(/],/g, '],\n ') )
```

The main optimization is that after each of the rows is resized, they are repeated instead of creating all of the # rows * scale rows. So, instead of processing n * scale arrays, only n arrays are processed. Another possible optimization might be that on some browsers, `arr.length *= n` might allocate all of the needed contiguous memory at once.

---

For comparison, the functional approach to the above is about 2 times slower :

```js
const scale1D = (arr, n) => [...Array(arr.length * n)].map((_, i) => arr[i / n | 0])

const scale2D = (arr, n) => scale1D( arr.map((row, i) => scale1D(row, n)), n )

console.time( 1e5 )
let a = scale2D([ [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 0, 1, 1] ], 1e5)
console.timeEnd( 1e5 )

let b = scale2D([ [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 0, 1, 1] ], 4)
console.log( JSON.stringify( b ).replace(/],/g, '],\n ') )
```

Comment: This is much faster. IShould've thought of inserting it backwards to make `not using splice` possible. Nice approach here.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of fun, you  can do it lazily if you're not accessing many values. Haven't tested this code much but should work

```js
        var a = [
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1], 
            [0, 0, 1, 0], 
            [0, 0, 1, 42] 
          ],
          scale = 4;
    
        for (var idx = 0; idx < a.length; idx++) {
            a[idx] = new Proxy(a[idx], {
              get: function(target, i) {
            return target[Math.floor(i/scale)];
          }
        });
        }
        a = new Proxy(a, {
              get: function(target, i) {
            return target[Math.floor(i/scale)];
          }
        });
    
        console.log(a[16-1][16-1])

        for (var ii = 0; ii < 16;ii++) {
          for(var j=0;j<16;j++){
            console.log(a[ii][j])
          }
        }
```